# Dask - Understanding diagnostics - memory:list

Tags: dask

I am working on some fairly complex application that is making use of Dask framework, trying to increase the performance. To that end I am looking at the diagnostics dashboard. I have two use-cases. On first I have a 1GB parquet file split in 50 parts, and on second use case I have the first part of the above file, split over 5 parts, which is what used for the following charts:

[image]

The red node is called "memory:list" and I do not understand what it is.
When running the bigger input this seems to block the whole operation.

[image]

Finally this is what I see when I go inside those nodes:

[image]

I am not sure where I should start looking to understand what is generating this `memory:list` node, especially given how there is no stack button inside the task as it often happens. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Red nodes are in memory.  So this computation has occurred, and the result is sitting in memory on some machine.

It looks like the type of the piece of data is a Python `list` object.  Also, the name of the task is `list-159...`, so probably this is the result of calling the `list` Python function.

Comment: Thank you for the response. If it was the result of an explicit call, would it not have a call stack button?